# Странное поведение SQL: возвращает Too Many Connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Проблема следующая: как-то странно получается, что при подключении к БД отдается Too Many Connections. Из одного скрипта. При этом из "соседнего" таких ошибок не наблюдается.

Т.е. открываю страницу с проблемным кодом - Too many connections. Тут же открываю другую - все в порядке.

Можно было бы погрешить на то, что вдруг откуда-то пошел огромный поток запросов, и что-то делается там с базой, что или соединений много, или запросы исполняются медленно, но этого нет. Все висит на локалке. Из кода во втором скрипте - только подключение к БД.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db = parent::connectDb();
}
```

Методы в родителе:

```
public function __construct(){
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/back/configs.php';
    $this->cfg = $cfg;
}

public function connectDb() {
    $cfgs = $this->cfg;     
    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host = ".$cfgs['host']."; dbname=".$cfgs['dbase']."",$cfgs['dblogin'],$cfgs['dbpass']);
        //$this->db = $db;
        return $db;
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $err =  $e->getMessage();
        require_once 'front/sysErr.php';
        die();
    }
}
```

Более ни в родителе, ни в дочернем нигде соединение с БД не используется, соответственно, и не вызывается.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` отдает инфу только о себе, ибо все соединения, как только получены данные, сразу убиваются.

Попытался перезагрузить сервер бд - не помогло.  В чем может быть проблемы? Как решить?

Comment: Я могу сказать лишь одно, продебагьте вашу функцию 'connectDb()' добавьте нейкий GLOBALS, и плюсуйте если вызвано два раза(а этого быть не должно на одной странице) то делать exit. Соединения умирает при выгрузке PDO обьекта. Знаете у меня тоже были такие проблемы, когда откуда-то не возьмись создавалось море соединений и памяти просто не хватало, но я множество раз отлаживал свои скрипты. И особенно 'require_once 'front/sysErr.php';
        die();' что-то это мне не нравится...

Comment: @ДенисКотляров в sysErr.php просто вьюшка.

Comment: И вообще не пробовали ли вы наследоватся от самого PDO, заделать свой класс обертку.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз, когда вызывается функция connectDb, создается новое подключение к базе. Т.е. каждый раз когда вызывается конструктор из "кода во втором скрипте" создается новое подключение к бд. Не знаю на сколько вы сильны в ооп, но посмотрите шаблон [singleton](https://habrahabr.ru/post/31375/).
Вы должны сделать так, что бы все запросы к базе выполнялись через одно соединение.

Если в общем, то нужно иметь класс со статической переменной, в которой хранится ваше подключение к бд. Каждый раз, когда вы пытаетесь получить подключение, проверять не пустая ли это переменная. Если пустая - создать новое подключение. Если нет - просто вернуть её, без создания нового подключения.

```
class Con
{
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    protected static $dbh;
    protected static $sets;

    public static function getConfigSettings()
    {
        require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/back/configs.php';
        return (object)$cfg;
    }

    public static function getDbh()
    {

        if (empty(self::$dbh)) {
            self::initConnection();
        }

        return self::$dbh;
    }

    protected static function initConnection()
    {
        if (!self::$dbh instanceof \PDO) {
            $sets = self::$sets;
            if (is_null($sets)) {
                $sets = self::getConfigSettings();
            }

            $dbh = new \PDO(
                "mysql:dbname={$sets->dbase};host={$sets->host};port={$sets->dbport}",
                $sets->dblogin,
                $sets->dbpass,
                array(
                    \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                )
            );

            self::$dbh = $dbh;              
        }

    }
}
```